# Managed proxy '/usr/bin/obfs4proxy' did not configure the specified outgoing proxy and will be terminated

Tags: configuration, onion-services, linux, bridge, error

Lately I have been trying to set up an obfs4 bridge on local area network.When running tor service,the log would show some message like this and the obfs4 loaded failed.What should i do?
[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you finished setting up the bridge (for example I don't see a `ServerTransportListenAddr` line). Can you follow the guide [here](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/) and then post your full torrc file?

Comment: In the Debian, ServerTransportListenAddr already exists.But the same problem occurred as Centos,and i found that the port 9443 for obfs4 opened and closed briefly.Full torrc like this---------------------------------------------------------------------------------Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 9100
Exitpolicy reject *:*
BridgeRelay 1
PublishServerDescriptor 0
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:9443
ExtORPort auto
HTTPProxy 10.0.5.212:8118
HTTPSProxy 10.0.5.212:8118